# I keep getting this error when I run the docker image of my nestjs application - @prisma/client did not initialize yet. Please run "prisma generate"

Tags: nestjs, prisma

When I run the docker image of the nestjs application built with the Dockerfile as shown below, I keep getting the error `@prisma/client did not initialize yet. Please run "prisma generate" and try to import it again.`. As you will see, `npx prisma generate` is in the Dockerfile

Here is the Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine AS development

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json ./

COPY pnpm-lock.yaml ./

RUN npm install -g pnpm

RUN pnpm install

COPY . .

RUN npx prisma generate

RUN pnpm run build

FROM node:alpine as production

ARG NODE_ENV=production

ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json ./

COPY pnpm-lock.yaml ./

RUN npm install -g pnpm

RUN pnpm install --prod

COPY --from=development /usr/src/app/dist ./dist

CMD ["node", "dist/main.js"]
```